# PrimeNG Calendar : set financial year picker

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

I am new to PrimeNG Calendar and I want calendar to display and select Indian financial year. Is this possible with PrimeNG Calendar? How? It will be really helpful if found a way. Thanks in advance.